# Magento2 read uploaded csv file

Tags: file-upload

I have upload CSV file but problem is i don't know how to read data of uploaded csv file in Magento2.
Please help me anyone.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can do that like you could in Magento 1. In Magento 1 you would use 
`new Varien_File_Csv`but in Magento 2 you can do the same with `\Magento\Framework\File\Csv`. You can use the following code.

In your `__construct()` inject the following classes:

```
protected $_fileCsv;

public function __construct(
   \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
   \Magento\Framework\Module\Dir\Reader $moduleReader,
   \Magento\Framework\File\Csv $fileCsv
) {
    $this->_moduleReader = $moduleReader;
    $this->_fileCsv = $fileCsv;
    parent::__construct($context); // If your class doesn't have a parent, you don't need to do this, of course.
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
// This is the directory where you put your CSV file.
$directory = $this->_moduleReader->getModuleDir('etc', 'Vendor_Modulename'); 

// This is your CSV file.
$file = $directory . '/your_csv_file_name.csv';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    $data = $this->_fileCsv->getData($file);
    // This skips the first line of your csv file, since it will probably be a heading. Set $i = 0 to not skip the first line. 
    for($i=1; $i<count($data); $i++) {
        var_dump($data[$i]); // $data[$i] is an array with your csv columns as values.
    }
}
```